# Getting the larger array

Tags: php

```
$arr1 = [1,2,3];
$arr2 = [1,2,3,4];
$arr3 = [1,2,3,4,5];

echo max( count($arr1), count($arr2), count($arr3) ); // returns 5
```

with `max` I do get the count, but don't know which array is larger. How do I get the larger array's reference (`$arr3` in this case)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use multidimensional array to store your all arrays then, loop through the multidimensional array and find your largest array,

```
$lgArraySize = 0; // used for comparing the size of array
$lgArray = array();   // used to store reference of largest array

foreach($arraylist as $array) {
    if(count($array) > $largeArraySize) {
         $lgArray = &$array;
         $lgArraySize = count($array);
    }
}

print_r($largeArray);
```

Here is the one liner code.(that you want)

```
function findMax( $row ){
   return count($row); 
}
$maxArrayPos = array_search(max( array_map("findMax", $multi )), array_map("findMax", $multi ));
print_r($multi[$maxArrayPos]);
```

You can make this as one liner.

Comment: So `$max = max( array_map(function( $row ){ return count($row); }, [$arr1, $arr2] ) );` ? But it would still print the `count`, not the array, right?

Comment: @3zzy check the solution, now it will print the first largest array you have. First because if you have many arrays of same length then it would print the first one.

Answer (score 3):

It's better to use indexes for such arrays, so that traversal is easy.
You can get reference to the larger array as follows -

```
$arr;
$arr[0] = [6,2,1,12,32,11];
$arr[1] = [1,2,3,4];
$arr[2] = [1,2,3,4,4,4,1,1,1,1];
$count = -1;//will hold max count
$big;//larger array will be stored here

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
  $curCount = count($arr[$key]);//curCount holds current array size
//checking for biggest array count
   if($curCount>$count){
     $count = $curCount;
     $big = &$arr[$key];
   }
}
var_dump($big);
```

Maybe the logic is too bulky though!

Comment: Well, I think I simplified my example too much. I don't have just two arrays. `if` statement is rather obvious for two.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
function laregr(){  
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    $large_array = array();
    if($numargs){
        $arg_list = func_get_args();
        $max = 0;       
        foreach($arg_list as $arg){
            if(is_array($arg)){
                $big = count($arg);         
                if($big >= $max ){
                    $max = $big;                
                    $large_array = $arg;
                }
            }
        }
    }   
    return $large_array;
}

$arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
$arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5];
$arr4 = [1,2,3,4, 5,6,7];

$max_array = laregr($arr1, $arr2, $arr4); // large($arr1, ...)
print_r($max_array);
```

Comment: "Try this" answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need?

```
$arr1 = [1,2,3];
$arr2 = [1,2,3,4];
$arr3 = [1,2,3,4,5];

$countmax = [
    "arr1" => $arr1,
    "arr2" => $arr2,
    "arr3" => $arr3,
];

$value = max($countmax);
print_r($value);
```

Oputput:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You may like to store all arrays inside an array and would like to do a foreach I think.

```
function max_length($array) {
    $max = 0;
    foreach($array as $child) {
        if(count($child) > $max) {
            $max = count($child);
        }
    }
    return $max;
}
```

check [this](https://gist.github.com/amalmurali47/9077238) why it is better approach .

Comment: Thanks but performance is not an issue for me, just need an elegant one-liner! ;)

Comment: than you may consider using array_map with count .